# Problems with micEconAid in r, Aidsest function error

Tags: r

Hi i am getting this error in my code when trying to estimate the "Almost Ideal Demand System" (AIDS)

"Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) :
error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'as.matrix': LU computationally singular: ratio of extreme entries in |diag(U)| = 1.815e-29"

**Here is my code:**

```
#install.packages("micEconAids")
#install.packages("dplyr")
library(micEconAids)
library(dplyr)


quintile1_shares <- read_excel("quintile 1 shares.xlsx")

Prices <- read_excel("Prices 1.xlsx")

quintile1_VND <- read_excel("quintile 1 VND.xlsx")
quintile1 <- subset(quintile1_VND, select = -`Eating, drinking & smoking`)

nprices <- c(colnames(Prices))
nshares <- c(colnames(quintile1_shares))

df1 <- merge(quintile1, quintile1_shares) %\>%
merge(Prices)

df2 <- as.matrix(df1)
aidsEst(nprices, nshares, "whole country", data =  df1, method = "LA", priceIndex = "S")
```

my data set has 7 observations and 41 variables that include "prices" and "shares" and "expenditure", i am suspecting that i have to few observations, could this be correct?

Was expecting an output of the aids estimate as shown in this document

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/micEconAids/vignettes/micEconAids_vignette.pdf

Comment: With only limited information on the data and model, it is difficult to answer. How many equations do you have, how many observations by equation, and how many parameters?

Comment: "my data set has 7 observations and 41 variable" with so few observations and so many variables, the error is most certainly telling you that either 1. you have too few observations, or 2. At least two of your variables are too highly correlated (perhaps even with a correlation of 1 or -1).